# Changing the colour of a row in UX

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to change the full width of the page to #263334 or RBG(230, 230, 250), I figured it would be within [row style="collapse"] but I couldn't get it to work, if anyone could give me a hand on this it would be greatly appreciated. I know this is a simple question but I've never really worked on websites before.

```css
[row style="collapse"]

[col span="3" span__sm="6"]

[ux_image id="966"]

[/col]
[col span="3" span__sm="6"]

[ux_image id="969"]

[/col]
[col span="3" span__sm="6"]

[ux_image id="970"]

[/col]
[col span="3" span__sm="6"]

[ux_image id="971"]

[/col]

[/row]
```

Comment: what am i looking at here? it's definitely not HTML.

Comment: This is not HTML, this is a UX-theme for WordPress from the looks of it.

Comment: You're right, my mistake, It's a UX theme